# Getting the date of the nth day after a given date

Tags: javascript, date

I am looking to find the date for, say, the 100th day after any given day. Is there a way to do that via javascript?

I was hoping it could be as simple as below, but it isn't quite that simple.

```
  var givenDay = new Date(01/01/2020);
  var hundredthDay = new Date(givenDay + 100);
  console.log(hundredthDay)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: One more thing to mention you have misspelt the variable name `hundredthDay` in console.log. Sometimes our code will be correct but these typos can cause a headache so always check for typos.

Comment: @MDMNauman—and *birthday* is undefined…

Comment: Thank you for the quick comments. Appreciate it. I edited my post after your comments and also looked at the answer from @norbitrial :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [`.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) combination.

> The `setDate()` method sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month.
>
> The `getDate()` method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time.

Adding the required days to `.getDate()` as the following:

```js
const givenDay = new Date('01/01/2020');
console.log(givenDay);

const result = new Date(givenDay.setDate(givenDay.getDate() + 1 + 100));
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This did help, thank you very much 